# Edit/Details form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

I have a Edit/Details form which has 4 user related fields. On click of Save, I save the edited fields to local storage (if supported) and display the same values in the Details view.

Below is the code which does that;

```
  var UserDataObj = {
name:"John",
email:"john@example.com",
phone:"9999999999",
desc:"some description"
}

/**
 * Check HTML5 Local Storage support
 */
function supports_html5_storage() 
{
    try {
        window.localStorage.setItem( 'checkLocalStorage', true );
        return true;
    } catch ( error ) {
        return false;
    };
};

/**
 * Save form data to local storage
 */
function saveFormData()
{
    if (supports_html5_storage())
    {
    $(".formFieldUserData").each(function(){
        UserDataObj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });

    localStorage.setItem('UserDataObj', JSON.stringify(UserDataObj));   
    }
}


/**
 * Set field values based on local storage
 */
function setFormFieldValues()
{
    if (supports_html5_storage())
    {
            var retrievedUserDataObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserDataObj'));
            if(retrievedUserDataObj)
            {
                $(".formFieldUserData").each(function(){
                    var currentKey = $(this).attr("name");
                    var retrievedValue = retrievedUserDataObj[$(this).attr("name")]
                    $("#"+currentKey).val(retrievedValue);
                    $("#"+currentKey+"Txt").html(retrievedValue);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $(".formFieldUserData").each(function(){
                    var currentKey = $(this).attr("name");
                    var userDataObjValue = UserDataObj[$(this).attr("name")]
                    $("#"+currentKey).val(userDataObjValue);
                    $("#"+currentKey+"Txt").html(userDataObjValue);
                });
            }
    }
    else
    {
        $(".formFieldUserData").each(function(){
        var currentKey = $(this).attr("name");
            if ($(this).val() != "")
            {
            var fieldValue = $(this).val();
            $("#"+currentKey).val(fieldValue);
            $("#"+currentKey+"Txt").html(fieldValue);
            }   
            else
            {
            var defaultuserDataObjValue = UserDataObj[$(this).attr("name")];
            $("#"+currentKey).val(defaultuserDataObjValue);
            $("#"+currentKey+"Txt").html(defaultuserDataObjValue);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

My question is;

1. This is a completely working code. But is there any further that I can do as far as best coding practices go.
2. Also performance wise, can I do anything to improve the overall code?

Comment: Note that this has been crossposted to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321636/check-javascript-coding-practice-and-overall-performance) (where it is closed) and [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190010/check-javascript-coding-practice-and-overall-performance) (where I think it is O/T).

Answer (score 3):

- You can start with how you code. Have them [indented properly](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and checked by a [quality-check tool](http://www.jshint.com/). Code-review doesn't only deal with optimization, but also maintainability of your code and that includes making it readable.
- After running it in JSHint, I found some minor problems in your code. Most notable are missing semi-colons. Although semi-colons in line endings are optional in JS, it's still best practice to include them. You could also avoid code packer/compressor errors by actually putting them in. This avoids your lines from being connected to the next line.
- Use strict comparison as much as possible in JS. JS treats ["falsy" values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Description) as `false`, which includes `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, a blank string and  `NaN`. For example, `` `"" == false `` is actually equal.
- Place your code in a namespace, or some inner-scope to avoid polluting the global scope.

For code related stuff:

```
(function (ns, $) {
  "use strict"; //prevents "bad practice"

  //variables needed for localStorage test
  var storage, fail, uid;

  //For flexibility, it would be best if your code 
  //wasn't build for a specific form only
  //instead, allow it to create instances and attach
  //to different forms with different default data
  function FormSave(selector, defaultValues) {
    this.defaultValues = defaultValues || {};
    this.dataName = selector;
    this.form = $(selector);
    this.userFields = $('.formFieldUserData', this.form);
  }

  //our save function
  FormSave.prototype.save = function () {

    var userData = {};

    //using the "early return" pattern to avoid further
    //code exectution if condition fails, and avoid
    //deep indentation
    if (!storage) {
      return;
    }

    //since each() assigns the current DOM element in
    //the collection as this, we can get name and value
    //directly from the DOM element, saving you function calls
    this.userFields.each(function () {
      userData[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    //set the items
    localStorage.setItem(this.dataName, JSON.stringify(userData));
  };

  //our setting function
  FormSave.prototype.set = function () {

    //cache the default values into this scope
    var defaultValues = this.defaultObject,
      retrievedValues;

    //if local storage is present, get and parse
    if (storage) {
      retrievedValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.dataName));
    }

    this.userFields.each(function () {

      //cache the current key
      var currentKey = this.name,
        //then the value to be used is:
        //if storage is present, use either the retrieved values or the default
        //if not, then use the present value or the default
        value = ((storage) ? retrievedValues[currentKey]: this.value) || defaultValues[currentKey];

      //for safe text insertion, use text() since it escapes the value first
      $("#" + currentKey + "Txt").text(value);
      $("#" + currentKey).val(value);
    });

    //our easy binding function exposed to our FormSave namespace
    ns.bind = function (selector) {
      return new FormSave(selector);
    };
  };

  //a quick test for localstorage
  //from: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern
  try {
    uid = new Date();
    (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
    fail = storage.getItem(uid) !== uid;
    storage.removeItem(uid);
    fail && (storage = false);
  } catch (e) {}

}(this.FormSave = this.FormSave || {}, jQuery));

//usage:

//bind this functionality to a form id'ed "someForm" with
//the given default values
var someForm = FormSave.bind('#someForm', {
  name: 'John',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  phone: '9999999999',
  desc: 'some description'
});

//then with the given reference, call save and set
someForm.save();
someForm.set();
```

When packed, it's this small!

```
(function (ns, $) {
  "use strict";
  var storage, fail, uid;

  function FormSave(selector, defaultValues) {
    this.defaultValues = defaultValues || {};
    this.dataName = selector;
    this.form = $(selector);
    this.userFields = $('.formFieldUserData', this.form)
  }
  FormSave.prototype.save = function () {
    var userData = {};
    if (!storage) {
      return
    }
    this.userFields.each(function () {
      userData[this.name] = this.value
    });
    localStorage.setItem(this.dataName, JSON.stringify(userData))
  };
  FormSave.prototype.set = function () {
    var defaultValues = this.defaultObject,
      retrievedValues;
    if (storage) {
      retrievedValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.dataName))
    }
    this.userFields.each(function () {
      var currentKey = this.name,
        value = ((storage) ? retrievedValues[currentKey] : this.value) || defaultValues[currentKey];
      $("#" + currentKey + "Txt").text(value);
      $("#" + currentKey).val(value)
    });
    ns.bind = function (selector) {
      return new FormSave(selector)
    }
  };
  try {
    uid = new Date();
    (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
    fail = storage.getItem(uid) !== uid;
    storage.removeItem(uid);
    fail && (storage = false)
  } catch (e) {}
}(this.FormSave = this.FormSave || {}, jQuery));
```